# how to set Http header X-XSS-Protection

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, xss

I have tried to put this:

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-XSS-Protection" content="0">
```

in the `<head>` tag but have had no luck. I am trying to get rid of pesky IE preventing cross-site scirpting

Comment: Try sending it as an HTTP header, maybe?

Comment: How do I do that? sorry Im new to setting headers

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I doubt it'd work as just a meta tag.  You may have to tell your web server to send it as a real header.

In PHP, you'd do it like

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

In ASP.net:

```
Response.AppendHeader("X-XSS-Protection","0")
```

In Apache's config:

```
Header set  X-XSS-Protection  0
```

In IIS, there's a section in the properties for extra headers.  It often has "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET" already set up in it; you'd just add "X-XSS-Protection: 0" to that same place.

Comment: Correct, it's not supported as a HTTP header.

Comment: do I add this to the .htaccess file within the root dir of my site?

Comment: If you want it to apply to the whole site, yes.

Comment: I have tried this in Coldfusion: <cfheader name="X-XSS-Protection" value="0"> But it's not working for me. Any idea about Coldfusion?

Comment: @AdilMalik: Sorry, i've never had to work with CF.  The docs look like that'd be right, though.  Is the header just not showing up in the response, or is there an error, or what?

Comment: how do you set this header in ASP Classic?

Comment: @cHao I'm using ASP web forms, Where should I need to add this `X-XSS-Protection` ?

Comment: @Sachith: Used to be, you'd set it in the IIS properties for the site...there's a tab for content settings IIRC. There might be a way to do it in web.config as well, but i don't know it. Codewise, you can probably add it right in the page's Load handler if you want.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using .Net MVC you can configure it through *customHeaders* in Web.Config.

To add these headers, go to the *httpprotocol* node and add those headers inside the *customHeaders* node.

```
<httpprotocol> 
    <customheaders> 
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"> 
           <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"></add>
        </remove>
    </customheaders> 
</httpprotocol>
```

I highly recommend this link that explain how can you can configuring Secure IIS Response Headers in ASP.NET MVC:
http://insiderattack.blogspot.com/2014/04/configuring-secure-iis-response-headers.html

Comment: tag closing was wrong you need to put those two lines inside customheaders tag
`<remove name="X-Powered-By"  /> 
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />`

Comment: @shadyshrif tag closing are fine on the code. Take a look:  </add></remove>

Comment: @mahmoud-samy please stop editing incorrectly this answer. Auto close tags isn't the solution, you close remove tag before add and it's wrong. Please take a look to the link that i posted. Are you tested the solution that you trying edit?.

Comment: @Equiman I've changed it after trying the existing answer. The suggested changes are actually running in production now.

Comment: @mahmoud-samy same here, are running on production. If it's an alternative answer then add it as comment or as another answer.

Comment: Changes suggested by shady sheriff are correct other wise it shows error.

Answer (score 5):

In Apache, you need to edit the config file, this file could be:

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

**/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

In the file you can add these lines at the end to enable HTTP Header XSS Protection:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Note: if `mod_headers` is external to the main Apache core (not compiled into Apache) then you would use `.so` rather than `.c` - ie. `<IfModule mod_headers.so>`

After that, save changes, and restart apache with:

> **sudo service apache2 restart**

or

> **sudo service httpd restart**

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I know this has been a long time ago but I came across it while searching for something and I don't think you put the `:` after the `Protection` if you are putting this inside a .htaccess file, do you?

Answer (score 3):

In `ASP Classic`, this tag will do it:

```
<% Response.AddHeader "X-XSS-Protection", "1" %>
```

Comment: I'm using ASP web forms, Where should I need to add this?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, if you use `.htaccess`, you will need to use double quotes:

```
Header set x-xss-protection "1; mode=block"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Turn on IE8-IE9 XSS prevention tools
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
```

This header is exclusive to Internet Explorer 8 and 9, it turns on cross site scripting protection in IE 8 and IE 9 which is turned off by default as it could potentially break some websites. To turn on the XSS filter, use the header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block". If you wish to prevent this filter from being turned on for your website set the headers value to "0";

http://stopmalvertising.com/security/securing-your-website-with-.htaccess/.htaccess-http-headers.html