# What triggers "Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting."?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to implement a workaround for missing CORS functionality in Internet Explorer. For GET requests I use JSONP, no problem here. For small POST/DELETE/PUT requests I also use JSONP by tunneling the requests through GET but this does not work for larger requests (Because the length of the GET URL is limited). So for large data I try to implement a form POST via an iframe. I can't read the response from this POST because of the same-origin policy so I fetch the response via a JSONP GET request after posting the data. Works great but sometimes I get a strange warning in IE 9:

```
Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting.
```

First I wondered what the hell IE is doing there because even when this warning appears everything still works correctly. Then I found out that IE replaces the content of the hidden iframe AFTER the POST answer (which I can't read and need anyway) with a "#" character.

So my workaround still works even when this warning appears but I would like to know what exactly triggers this warning so maybe I can modify my CORS workaround to get rid of this warning. Any hints?

Comment: IE protects against [reflected XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Non-persistent) and I think that it checks whether the server response contains data that was passed to it in the request in an unescaped form. If you don't need the response to your POST request anyway, then I guess not sending anything there will solve this?

Comment: The response is already empty. I'm not wasting bandwidth for data I can't read anyway.

Comment: Did you look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635403/how-to-set-http-header-x-xss-protection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635403/how-to-set-http-header-x-xss-protection)?

Comment: @Artem: Yes, this header fixes my problem. Do you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @WladimirPalant Do you have a source to support "I think that [IE] checks whether the server response contains data that was passed to it in the request in an unescaped form"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the `X-XSS-Protection` header on your server. This will tell IE to disable XSS protection on your site.