# How to Prevent IE from modifying pages for `Cross-Site Scriptng Prevention`

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What triggers “Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045665/what-triggers-internet-explorer-has-modified-this-page-to-help-prevent-cross-si)

IE is modifying my pages and puts # automatically to the hyperlinks when I redirect a page via JavaScript.

Here is the message I am seeing:

> Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting.
>       Click here for more information...

[image]

I want to programatically stop IE from doing this.

Comment: How did you get the message? What is in your code?

Comment: @Madbreaks I haven't tried anything yet. Because I don't know at all how to programatically stop IE from doing this. I couldn't find much help on google as well.

Comment: Are you using localhost as your tesing/dev machine?

Comment: @Neal my code just redirects from one page to another (within the same domain) using javascript `windows.location` and when I reach on the next page, all of my hyperlinks are screwed up by IE.

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Click here for more information..." Since the above is an image, we can't click it.

Comment: @AdilMalik can you put all of that into your OP please?

Comment: @AdilMalik Try using actual machine name instead

Comment: You haven't said which version of IE is doing this.

Comment: **O** riginal **P** ost @AdilMalik

Comment: @Blazemonger I have seen it on different machine and on different versions. But mine is IE8 right now.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Seems to be .. let me try that. One moment please.