# iframe src missing in chrome !! working fine in firefox and ie

Tags: iframe

I get my iframeurl using `request.getAttribute` and I loaded directly in to the body by `<%= iframeurl %>` but this doesn't work in Chrome. working fine in Firefox. if I gave directly the iframe URL in JSP it is working in Chrome!

What's the problem? Could anybody help me?

Comment: i gave like below<body>
<%
String iframeurl;
url=(String)request.getAttribute("iframeurl");
%>
<%= iframeurl %>
</body>

Answer (score 3):

This is a security feature of Chrome to prevent [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks. When the iframe src url is posted in the http request you will not be able to use it in an iframe without applying a special header to the receiving page: **X-XSS-Protection: 0**

You could also avoid sending the iframe element in the post, and instead just send the src url.

See also: [Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque)