# Youtube embed link not displaying in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm making resourceful routes for youtube videos. So, a person just pastes the youtube embed link in the form. In the controller I have a normal set of resourceful actions:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @videos = Video.all
  end

  def new
    @video = Video.new
  end

  def create
    Video.create(params[:video])
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end

  def destroy
    Video.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end
end
```

And in the view I'm just displaying it: (in Haml)

```
- @page_title = 'Video'

#videos
  %ul
    = list_of(@videos) do |video|
      %h1= video.title
      != video.link
      = link_to "Delete", video_path(video), :method => :delete

  = link_to "Add new video", new_video_path

  %p#top
    = link_to 'Go to top ↑', '#'
```

For the one who don't use Haml, `!=` escapes the string. `video.link` holds the YouTube embed code

The problem is that, when I create a new video, and when it redirects me back to the index page, the newly created video isn't displayed (the other ones are normally displayed). Only after I refresh the page, it's normally displayed.

I saw in the web inspector that the `src` attribute is missing from the `iframe` (so that's why the video isn't displayed). But when I look in the page source, everything is normal there. So, thinking it may be Javascript's fault, I tried disabling it. But nothing changed.

Comment: You wrote `And in the view I'm just displaying it.` -- but that's everything... please add the view code for the iframe or javascript widget you're using

Comment: when you get redirected to #index, does the title and/or delete link show? Also, is there any background processing that takes updates the record after it is created?

Comment: Is `video.link` the iframe code? You're still not showing the iframe code you're using....

Comment: All of the links are shown. No, there is no background process (there is just one administrator, so I figured there is no need). About the `video.link`, yes, it holds a YouTube embed link, for example `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kWakZcEGB38" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to escape it using haml... I think you want to call

```
video.link.html_safe
```

Note: if the user is pasting in the link, this is very unsafe.

***Update*** --- If you have the javascript develop console open, you'll see this error pop up:

```
**Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.**
```

Check [this answer for why it's refusing to due XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque) Here's a method that is both safe and works. You'll paste in the youtube ID in the text field: ibWYROwadYs

**index.erb**

```
<% if session[:youtube].present? %>
  <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=session[:youtube]%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag load_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :youtube_id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Clear", clear_path, :method => :delete %>
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def smth
    session[:youtube] = params[:youtube_id]
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end

  def clear
    session.clear
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I didn't worry about safety because only an administrator will have access to this. I'm making the website for that person, so I'm just doing a basic CMS.

Comment: It didn't work. Sorry, I forgot that I have to tell you that, instead of just not accepting.

Comment: can you `=debug video.link` ?? that'll tell you if the link is stored in the database or not.

Comment: Yes, it's stored in the database (I mentioned that it appears when you just refresh #index after being redirected to it). The problem doesn't happen if I enter custom text instead of a YouTube embed link. I'm 100% sure it has something to do with it being an iframe. Wow, I just tried reproducing the problem in the simplest possible way, making a new rails project, adding a "home" controller, and only changing [this](https://gist.github.com/1691441) code (did it in ERB just in case), and there is still that error. Try to do the similar, and you should get the same.

Comment: I just found out something interesting. If, instead of a form, I use a simple link to the action which puts the youtube embed link in a session, this problem won't happen.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see the link above, I linked you a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1691441) which reproduces this error on a new rails application. After pasting that code and runnig the server, just click submit, and watch iframe taking up space, but not displaying. Then try refreshing. What is a remote form?

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it know :). Since a person will be pasting YouTube embed link, I cannot actually achieve that the iframe isn't sent in the form. But I also found a temporary fix to just substitute double quotes with single quotes when retrieving the new record from the database when I'm redirected back to #index. But now I know why it happens.