# Chrome gives the error "Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request", after redirect... why?

Tags: php, google-chrome, xss

I have a form where there is field that you use to paste the usual google maps embed HTML code. After I send this form to the server (via POST), the server saves everything to the db and then gives back a redirect (GET redirect, simple URL) to the final page that contains the stored content.

Firefox works (I guess ie too), but chrome comes out with "Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request". I found another answer that deals with the problem on So: [Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque). The fact is that I could understand it, if I was displaying the final page after the POST with the form, but how can it be after the redirect? I even had a peek to the redirect GET request and it contains not the "CODE" (that is only the EMBED code from google maps, an IFRAME).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

before post, you can replace the textarea content with its urlencoded or base64 equivalent with javascript. then post it to your server, and then decode it and save to the database.