# Twitter API: refused to execute a javascript

Tags: google-chrome, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque)

I'd like to display my latest tweet on my homepage. First, I checked out the Twitter widgets, but they were too big and didn't fit my design. So I decided to use the Twitter API. I tried using the following piece of code:

```
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1"></script>
```

But when I check the console log in chrome, I see this error:

> Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found
>   within request.

Obviously, no tweets are shown now :(
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There's an explanation of it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/ but I have no idea why it's showing up

Comment: and check the Network panel in the Dev Tools to find out which script is blocked

Comment: I checked the network panel and all requests were successful. The API-request gives a JSONP response with that latest tweet included, so I guess there's something wrong with the blogger.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself by using a local JavaScript to parse the tweet. I downloaded the blogger.js, modified a bit (removed some styles) and uploaded it to my server. Now it's working like a charm.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Indeed, but only 24 hours (or 48, can't remember) after posting.