# How can I add an HTTP header in my Wordpress implementation

Tags: wordpress, http

As per [Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque/1547887#1547887), I would like to send this code with pages of my Wordpress site:

```
<?php header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");?>
```

Where do I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can it to the top of the index.php in the wordpress docroot.  You need to modify the header before ANY content is sent.

If you update your site with a new worpress version you could lose this change.  Just be aware.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with messing with the core code? Perhaps in a theme?

Comment: @KennethVogt that would be best, but have to find a file that loads before a single bit is sent to the client browser.