# Asp.net Webform, Swf File and Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, flash, webforms

I have a problem with ASP.NET webform, SWF files and Google Chrome.

I'm working with a form contained `runat="server"` attribute, inside the form, a button contained `runat="server"` and `onclick='Button1_Click'` attributes on asp.net page. The swf files show on first click on the button. When I post the form again, swf files not showing. I mean, there's a problem on second postback of the form. It works any browsers except Chrome. Is there any solving method for this issue?

PS: There's no update panels. The swf files place into asp.net repeater that places into the form.

Edit: Error console returns me "Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request." message.

Comment: Any log in the console? What about network requests in the debug window?

Comment: It returns me "Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request." error message on second postback.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque).

Comment: Thank you @Adriano. `Response.AddHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "0");` worked for me.