# jQuery one-page scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this jQuery plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) to get a one-page scroll effect.

However, as you can see on [this page](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/projectklang/), it doesn't work and instead just locks the scroll.

jQuery is working fine - I can run an alert for example. Might the CSS file that comes with the plugin be conflicting with my existing one?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to call these two files from your server

1. `https://raw.github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.min.js`
2. `https://raw.github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.js`

It is to prevent XSS (cross-site scripting) attacks [Check more details about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque#answer-1547887)

Comment: As in host them locally? I've done so (see page source) and it hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more compatibility with old browsers such as IE8, 9, Opera 12... and some more functionalities, here's another great plugin for it, is called **fullPage.js**:

- [Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
- [Page](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)

Some features it adds to the one you are using:

- Use it over IE 8 and old browsers with no CSS 3 support.
- Compatibility with touch devices
- Plenty of more options and functions
- [Scroll bar](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) for a better UX experience
- Use of anchors in the URL
- Add a live menu.
- Slide throw the page using the keyboard shorcuts (arrows, spacebar, pageUp/pageDown, home, end...)
- Add horizontal sliders.