# How to scroll one a page height on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[This is my test page.](http://crelation.com/freeMag/demo1/demo.html)

I want to ask how to scroll once a page height on mobile device, just like this page works on PC?

I'm now using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        responsiveFallback: 600,
        loop: true
    });
});
```

But it doesn't works on mobile.

How can i do the same effect on mobile?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Here onepage_scroll is jquery plugin right???

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057204/jquery-one-page-scroll-not-working

Comment: Yes, it's jquery plugin.
I try to add two files, but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var H = $(window).height();
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: H}, 1500, 'easeOutBounce');
```