# How to deal with Chrome X-XSS-Protection in a right way?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox, xss

I run my application in Chrome, it has a error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://example.com/info?no=31&magic=1184' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

From this topic, I know it should to set http header X-XSS-Protection : 0

[Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque)

I use RoR to set it as this:

```
def info
  response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '0'
  # Other logic
end
```

But the result is,the http header still:

```
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection:0
```

---

When I try it in Firefox, the http header is:

```
X-XSS-Protection    0, 1; mode=block
```

And can run perfectly.

Why it has `1; mode=block`? How to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with XSS protection. You need to change the Content-Type HTTP header on http://example.com/info?no=31&magic=1184 from text/html to text/javascript.